# .htaccess for appending https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have searched for quite sometime to get a solution or a hint to my query but didnt find anything valuable. Basically i have my application which is SSL secured. All i want is that

1. If users try to open the application without https and www, it should automatically append "`https://www`"
2. If user enters "`https://mydomain.com`", it should change to "`https://www.mydomain.com`"
3. If user enters "`www.mydomain.com`", it should change to "`https://www.mydomain.com`"

I understand this can be achieved through .htaccess but i am a lot ignorant about the way these files are written.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Anubhava - Worked like a charm in one go. Thanks a lot. If you dont mind and have little bit of time, can you explain me each line. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Sure I can explain. First rule is checking whether host name doesn't start with `www.`. If condition is true then redirect everything to `https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` which simply means prefix host name with `www.`. Second rule is checking whether HTTPS isn't set for the current URL. If this condition is true then redirect everything to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` which simply means use HTTPS for the current URL. Please refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for detailed documentation.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Very nice explanation and easy to understand. Thanks again. Good Luck !!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off checks if HTTPS is off. If it is indeed off (the URL doesn't contain https://), then the rewrite rule applies and the user is redirected.