# Append www into URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a WordPress site which works fine if I access it through the full name of the domain, example `www.example.com`. However if I try to access it without typing the `www` e.g `example.com`, I get the  following error:

```
Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The only solution I can think of is to append / rewrite any request to `example.com` to `www.example.com`. How can I achieve this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please always remeber to Google first. There is a bazillion resources dealing with this exact issue.

Comment: true that but nothing works, for instance this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810989/htaccess-for-appending-https-www?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this above any wordpress rules in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What I did was I created the htaccess file and added the codes in it. However I get the error during loading the page. "The page cannot be displayed"

Comment: @abiieez you add the htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: Its in a folder called `wwwroot`, where wp-admin,wp-content and wp-includes reside.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encountered this with WordPress. I got it fixed by installing this plugin https://github.com/jacopotarantino/WordPress-Cross-Domain-Plugin and add the site into "Allowed Domains".